# Running WCF Server From Admin Command Prompt Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to understand WCF services and am following the GettingStarted tutorial found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-and-run-a-basic-wcf-service

When I run the project through visual studio the service succesfully starts up, which I can verify by visiting the populated service page at http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService.

However, when I start a command prompt as administrator and navigate to the bin directory and execute GettingStartedHost.exe, the page no longer displays.

What could be causing this discrepancy? What is the difference from running GettingStartedHost.exe from the command prompt vs from Visual Studio?

I want to be able to host my service on localhost from the command prompt and not from visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between running the service from CMD with administrative privilege and starting from Visual studio.
Given that the official documentation is too old, I try to reproduce your issue. But I found we still can access the service from the browser with  The configuration in the class library is no longer valid, the Url base address and the binding type is taken with console application configuration. The service description page based on the HttpGetEnabled property. Therefore, the service description URL is the service base URL instead of the service endpoint address(http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService).

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1), baseAddress);
            try
            {
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

Here is an example of hosting the service in Console application without referring to any other project. I wish it is useful to you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");


                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                //pause
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();

    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then we access the service definition page, http://localhost:21011
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.